# Return the index corresponding to the median value from a list

Tags: python, statistics, probability

I want to write a function `median_index(A)` that returns the index of the median given a distribution A ( A is a list with values associated with each index).

I have sorted out the way to get the median value but now I want to have the position (index) where that median is when the list A is sorted.

```py
def median_index(P):
    l = sorted(P)
    l_len = len(P)
    if l_len < 1:
        return None
    if l_len % 2 == 0 :
        return ( l[(l_len-1)/2] + l[(l_len+1)/2] ) / 2.0
    else:
        return l[(l_len-1)/2]

median_index([0.12,0.04,0.12,0.12,0.2,0.16,0.16,0.08])
```

That produces 5 as the result. 5 is the last position where 0.12. This is the index of the median 0.12 when I sort the list and calculate the median which is 0.12.

Comment: You can't really return the index of the median because if there are an even number of samples the median is the average of the n/2 and n/2+1 values which will only exist if the two values are the same. That may not correspond to any sample. I also think that `return ( l[(l_len-1)/2] + l[(l_len+1)/2] ) / 2.0` uses the wrong elements, and it should be `return ( l[(l_len)/2] + l[(l_len+1)/2] ) / 2.0` as it would need to use adjacent cells.

Comment: Thanks Deepstop. I found a way around it with a count variable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list.index(element)`